# Weird behaviour with for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, for-loop

I have this image table that has two columns and 20 rows. When executing this for loop, all the rows are working okay except for the first row, which only displays the first image on the left. It's really weird; is there something wrong with the order of the execution?

```
var image= [];
var rows=5;        
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    var avatar = test[i].image; // The profile image

    if(i % 2 === 0){
        image[i]= Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            top:row,
            image:avatar
            align:right
            });
        win.add(image[i]);
        //trying to increase the image
        row =row+200;
    } else if(i % 2 === 1) {
        image[i]= Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            top:row,
            image:avatar
            align:left
            });
        win.add(image[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your else if can be changed to a simple else statement. i % 2 will always be either 0 or 1.

Comment: 1. Both branches of the if-else statement contain 6 lines of equivalent code (?!) Place that code out of the if-else statement. 2. Don't declare variables inside a for loop. It suggests that that variable is declared multiple times, which it isn't. Declare the variable on the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i=0, i%2=0, show the image (supposed to be right), row+=200;

i=1, i%2=1, show the image (left side), row stays same

i=2, i%2=0, show the image (right side), row+=200

0%2 = 0, and that represents your right side image, and then it goes to the next line.  Just need to play around with where you increment row and which side your loop starts with.

Comment: dont change the initial value, switch the conditions! otherwise you will miss the 1st image.

Comment: yeah probably better to do i+1 % 2 or something.

Comment: i switched the conditions but it deosnt work, when i chnaged the intial value it started working!! is that bad thing if i chnaged the intial value :)) thanks for the advice

Comment: If i=1 when it's set, test[0] is overlooked.  I think if you just change if(i %2 === 0) to if( (i+1) %2 === 0) along with the else if, it should correct the problem.